# How to convert pandas DataFrame back to Mltable (Azure SDK v2)

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk

In my code I read data as `mltable` for the `Azure SDK v2`. Then I convert that into pandas `DataFrame`, do some work on the data and then I want to save it back as an `mltable` in order to use that as a part of my pipeline.

Unfortunately I was unable to find any proper documentation with straightforward answer to that.

My code looks like this:

```py
path = {
    'file': f'azureml://subscriptions/{subscription_id}/resourcegroups/{resource_group}/workspaces/{workspace_name}/datastores/my_container/paths/raw_data/my_data.csv'
    }

tbl = mltable.from_delimited_files(paths=[path])
df = tbl.to_pandas_dataframe()
```

At the same time I wonder if I should save it as a `URI file` in the Data section in order to use that for my pipeline component? If so I would also be happy to get some inputs on how to convert pandas into `URI file`. I found no examples in the official documentation.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create `URI file` from a `Dataframe`, you need to create a `CSV File` with the dataframe and then upload the CSV File.

To do this you can use  [AzureMachineLearningFileSystem Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-fsspec/azureml.fsspec.spec.azuremachinelearningfilesystem?view=azure-ml-py)
Below is a code snippet to do the task:

```py
from azureml.fsspec import AzureMachineLearningFileSystem
from azureml.core import Workspace
ws=Workspace.from_config()
import pandas as pd

data = {'column1': [1, 2, 3], 'column2': ['A', 'B', 'C']}
df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_sample.to_csv('sample_data.csv', index=False)

uri = f'azureml://subscriptions/{ws.subscription_id}/resourcegroups/{ws.resource_group}/workspaces/{ws.name}/datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/'
fs = AzureMachineLearningFileSystem(uri)


# Upload a file
fs.upload(lpath='sample_data.csv', rpath='raw_data2/sample_data.csv', recursive=False, **{'overwrite': 'MERGE_WITH_OVERWRITE'})
```

This will create a csv file in the datastore.
[image]

Again, you can access the updated CSV file URI with `mltable`.
[image]